# How can I sort the X axis in a Barplot in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have binned data that looks like this:

```
  (8.048,18.05] (-21.95,-11.95] (-31.95,-21.95]   (18.05,28.05] (-41.95,-31.95]
             81              76              18              18             12
    (-132,-122]     (-122,-112]     (-112,-102]     (-162,-152]  (-102,-91.95]
              6               6               6               5              5
(-91.95,-81.95]     (-192,-182]   (28.05,38.05]   (38.05,48.05]  (58.05,68.05]
              5               4               4               4              4
  (78.05,88.05]     (98.05,108]     (-562,-552]     (-512,-502]    (-482,-472]
              4               4               3               3              3
    (-452,-442]     (-412,-402]     (-282,-272]     (-152,-142]  (48.05,58.05]
              3               3               3               3              3
  (68.05,78.05]       (118,128]       (128,138]     (-582,-572]    (-552,-542]
              3               3               3               2              2
    (-532,-522]     (-422,-412]     (-392,-382]     (-362,-352]    (-262,-252]
              2               2               2               2              2
    (-252,-242]     (-142,-132] (-81.95,-71.95]       (148,158]  (-1402,-1392]
              2               2               2               2              1
  (-1372,-1362]   (-1342,-1332]     (-942,-932]     (-862,-852]    (-822,-812]
              1               1               1               1              1
    (-712,-702]     (-682,-672]     (-672,-662]     (-632,-622]    (-542,-532]
              1               1               1               1              1
    (-502,-492]     (-492,-482]     (-472,-462]     (-462,-452]    (-442,-432]
              1               1               1               1              1
    (-432,-422]     (-352,-342]     (-332,-322]     (-312,-302]    (-302,-292]
              1               1               1               1              1
    (-202,-192]     (-182,-172]     (-172,-162] (-51.95,-41.95]  (88.05,98.05]
              1               1               1               1              1
      (108,118]       (158,168]       (168,178]       (178,188]      (298,308]
              1               1               1               1              1
      (318,328]       (328,338]       (338,348]       (368,378]      (458,468]
              1               1               1               1              1
```

How can I plot this data so that the bin is sorted from most negative on the left to most positive on the right? Currently my graph looks [like this](http://docs.google.com/Doc?id=dcvdrfrh_5cm5qkchw).  Notice that it is not sorted at all.  In particular the second bar (`value = 76`) is placed to the right of the first:

```
 (8.048,18.05] (-21.95,-11.95]
            81              76
```

This is the command I use to plot:

```
barplot(x,ylab="Number of Unique Tags", xlab="Expected - Observed")
```

Comment: "Hi," and two line breaks, which depending on storage in the database could equal even more characters. At the very least two.

Comment: BTW, who made Rich B the decider of "acceptable behavior".

Comment: Yeah, the character count is based on the HTML, not the Markdown. Earlier today I edited a post just to add backquotes around some code, and the default edit summary was "Added 13 characters in body". `` isn't 13 characters, but <code></code> is.

Comment: We should amend Jeff's Blog post to say, "Respect the original Author, or respect the editor that thinks he knows what the original author wanted; or respect the editor that doesn't like your changes and the original author's subseqent approval of your changes."

Comment: I have the same question. Does anyone know how to order bins? As per FryGuy's comment, bins are a mathematical notation and can be created easily in R using "cut" or "cut2". Like neversaint, I am trying to order these on my x-axis. When bins are all positive, the ordering happens correctly. But not if one bin has a negative number! –  WGray 6 mins ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really want to help answer your question, but I gotta tell you, I can't make heads or tails of your data. I see a lot of opening parenthesis but no closing ones. The data looks sorted descending by whatever the values are on the bottom of each row. I have no idea what to make out of a value like "(8.048,18.05]"

Am I missing something obvious? Can you make a more simple example where your data structure is not a factor?

I would generally expect a data frame or a matrix with two columns, one for the X and one for the Y.

See if this example of sorting helps (I'm sort of shooting in the dark here)

```
tN <- table(Ni <- rpois(100, lambda=5))
r <- barplot(tN)

#stop here and examine the plot
#the next bit converts the matrix to a data frame,
#  sorts it, and plots it again

df<-data.frame(tN)
df2<-df[order(df$Freq),]
barplot(df2$Freq)
```

Comment: He is using the general mathematics range notation, [] is closed interval, () is open interval. So for his first bin: (8.048,18.05] = 81, that means that for the range 8.048 < x <= 18.05, there were 81 elements in that range.

Comment: Ohhhhh! Thank you for straightening that out. I had not seen output from R that looked like that, so I was flummoxed.